# Enabling the web2py profiler on pythonanywhere

Tags: profiling, web2py, pythonanywhere

There is a (seemingly) simple way to generate profiler information about a web2py installation, by just adding a -F flag.  How, if it is possible, would this be enabled on a web2py site hosted on http://pythonanywhere.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the WSGI file for your web app, you currently have a line:

```
from gluon.main import wsgibase as application
```

replace it with:

```
from gluon.main import appfactory
application = appfactory(profiler_dir="/tmp")
```

and your web2py app will log profiling data to the /tmp directory.